# Display data in table using v-for laravel vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, v-for

I'm having a trouble why the data did not display in my table, I've been using `v-for in tr` to display the data info, but it did not work, Is there any wrong with my code? please check this out.It would be great if anybody could help me out, thank you so much in advance!.

*But it seems it returns the data*

[image]

*table*

```
 <tbody>
     <tr v-for="listuser in users" :key="listuser.id" :value="listuser.id" >
         <td class="pl-0">
              <a href="#" >{{listuser.username}}</a>
                  <span class="text-muted font-weight-bold text-muted d-block">Programmer II</span>
          </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
```

*My Script*

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users: [],
        }
    },  
    created() {
        this.getUsers();
    },
    mounted() {
        // this.ini();
    },
    methods: {
        // ini() 
        getUsers() {
            axios.get(BASE_URL + "/users/listUsers").then(response => {
                this.users = response.users;
            });
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

*My Controller*

```
use App\Models\User;
public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(User::all());
    }
```

*model*

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
   use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, HasRoles, WithPaginate;
   use ExtendedEloquentTrait;
   protected $guard = 'users';

   protected $fillable = [     
      'username',
      'email',
      'password'
   ];
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use the function call inside mount function. Secondly try the loop with the following syntax.

```
<tr v-for="(item,index) in users" :key="index">
          <td class="pl-0">
          <a href="#" >{{item.username}}</a>
              <span class="text-muted font-weight-bold text-muted  d-block">Programmer II</span>
           </td>
</tr>
```

And when you get the api response set the users like below.

```
this.users = response.data.users
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried to called the function in mount function and tried your loop above but it didn't display the data at all.

Comment: what's the index used for?

Comment: index actually refers to the the current iteration value like 0,1,2,3 and so on

Comment: Thanks for your response but the result is always the same it did not display the data :(

Comment: Still can't find the problem need help

Comment: Just echo inside blade like this .

{{users.length}} 
{{users}}

Comment: and check what exactly you are receiving

Comment: Thank you I just figured out that I have problem in my models

Comment: guard property or something else ?

Comment: Yes it is guard property

Comment: hah I was about to mention that in the next comments. . Well, great you figure out.